# Hive dynamic partitioned table build from non-partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a Hive table SMART_STG.CALL_RECORDS which is external non-partitioned text file table. I need to copy the data into a new target table. The requirements for the target table is:

- Should have same structure as source table - SMART_STG.CALL_RECORDS
- Should have partitioning on new column 'ingest_datetime'
- This new table should get created automatically

I know I can create the partitioned table manually by using describe option and adding the `partitioned BY(ingest_datetime string)` but how do I build this table dynamically so that my code works on any table?

Sample structure of my source table.

```
create table SMART_STG.CALL_RECORDS
(
 Call_Number String,
 Dollar_Amt Decimal(3,2),
 Call_Value Decimal(3,2),
 Date_Month INT,
 Date_year INT
 )
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
 LOCATION '/smart_stg/CallRecords'
```